# How do I make an object not enter another one?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am currently learning blender and I started doing this damn donut, I've tried many times and one of the problems I'm having now is that when i grab the top icing and pull down it enters on the donut, how can i solve this? Also, the edge of the icing drop don't seem kinda soft. sorry I'm still learning :)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DNR: Use Shrink/Fatten to increase the icing size; only move vertices in the Z plane; use Shrink/Fatten to decrease the icing size; and use a solidify modifier to give the finished look.

The only way you can prevent that if you are doing something similar to how Price teaches that tutorial is to grab the vertex above the one you have current selected and pull the vertices away from the donut.  If you're just trying to randomize the border of the icing to make it look more organic, here's a technique I would use instead:

- Separate the icing from the donut and make it another object as he does in the tutorial.
- Select the "icing" object and enter Edit mode.
- Use the Shrink/Fatten tool to make the icing bigger (Shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>S</kbd> and move the cursor.  Left Click to finish.) Don't overdo it. You just want it far enough so that it's easy to do the next bit.
  [image: icing after shrink/fatten]
- When you move the vertices using random proportional editing, restrict the motion to the Z axis and don't go far enough to drag a vertex "into" the donut.  (To constrain the movement use <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> as the move command)
  [image: A few vertices moved]
- Use the Shrink/Fatten command to reduce the size of icing so that it is just enough above the surface of the donut so that the solidify modifier that you apply next will leave a reasonable thickness for the border.
- Add the solidify modifier and set the size so that the icing penetrates the donut.
- Use a Subdivision modifier to smooth out both the donut and the icing; and give them both subdivision modifiers and smooth shading
  [image]

Comment: omg thanks a lot it really helped, now it's fixed (https://prnt.sc/KOvQ0MdGukXs)

Comment: You're very welcome.  There's nothing wrong with Price's approach, but this one just happens to work better for me.

Answer (score 0):

From your image, the distance between the loops is too much. Create a loopcut between the last loop and the preceding loop and scale it up a bit using the shift button.